# laravel framework : is it safe to move index.php from public folder to the project root?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

i know the public folder is there for a reason , but i have to upload a laravel project on a shared hosting and i dont have access to server to change the host root to `public_html/public` so it have to load from public_html

so i've moved index.php and htaccss from public to root and it works fine , but now anyone can directly access project files models / controller / etc.... im not sure if it's harmful but i know its not super safe !

so is it safe to do this ?  any other option beside getting a vps ?

*pleas note im just a programmer and it's not my decision where to upload the project so pleas dont talk about how cheap and easy is to get a vps these days !*

Comment: you can use an .htaccss file to stop public access even when files are under the public dir

Comment: @rtfm yes but i have to put an htaccess on every single directory .... that would be plan b

Comment: depending on server set up the .htaccees is read through subdirectories. if that is not the case for your server just symlink them

Comment: If the models/controller/ etc are used via 'include' then they can be off the public_html folders anyway if memory serves me correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - put all the project folders in separate folder like `laravel`

2 - move the laravel folder before public_html so it wont be accessible

3 - move all the files from public folder into the project root (public_html) then delete public folder

4 - edit index.php add ../laravel to the path

Answer (score 2):

In the root folder, you need just to rename the file

server.php

to

index.php

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, no.  It isn't safe.  Depending on how your server is set up a malicious user may be able to download your PHP files as text files and read them... including things like DB passwords and SQL query structures.  That's bad.  An axiom of web programming is "never trust anybody, not even yourself."  That includes your server setup.  Best practice is to move all principle PHP files outside the web root.

If you cannot do that, your only option is to push all the files down one level inside the web root (e.g., `/web_root/secure_directories/.`) and use `.htaccess` to stop everyone but localhost from looking in that directory.  Your `.htaccess` file would look like this:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Theoretically, if all your principle PHP files are in one subfolder (which may then contain many more subfolders), then you only need do this for the "top" folder.

Note that it's ideal to gain access to a directory outside of your web root simply because `.htaccess` functions slow your server down.  It won't be noticable if you don't have a lot of visitors... but it will when you do.

Comment: Almost true, but if anyone can download php files as text it won't matter what folder they are in on the server. Chances of a server being so badly set up are slim I would think. There is nothing wrong with having index.php in serverroot imho.

Comment: I should have been more specific.  As a habit, my `index.php` file has but a single line: `<?php require("/protected_path/my_index.php");`  This guarantees that everything I want protected is protected.  Better safe than sorry, especially if you don't have control of the server.